# proof of 1) $|a| = 0 \iff a = 0$ and 2) $|a| \ge 0$

Tags: real-numbers

On the internet there are many proofs but very summary

Definition
$|a| = $
$a$ if $a \ge 0$
$-a$ if $a < 0$

Proposition 1
 $|a| = 0 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow a = 0$

$\Rightarrow$)

Suppose that $|a| = 0$
This implies that $a\ge 0$ xor $a<0$ 
Case $a<0$
$|a| = -a$ by hypothesis $-a= 0$
As $a<0$
$a + (-a)<0 + 0$
$0<0$ (!contradiction)
Case $a \ge 0$
$|a| = a$ by hypothesis $a = 0$

$\Leftarrow$)
Suppose that $a= 0$
$|a| = a$ by hypothesis $|a| = 0$

proposition 2
$|a| \ge 0$
case $a \ge 0$
$|a| = a$ by hypothesis $|a| \ge 0$
case $a < 0$
$|a| = -a$
As $a<0$
$a+(-a)<0+(-a)$
$0<-a$
$0<|a| \Rightarrow 0 \le |a|$

are valid my proofs?

Comment: Can you mention your definition of $|a|$?

Comment: I already put it

Comment: Ok, thanks, didn't see that

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: your proofs are valid!

Comment: In fact, you only have $|a|=0\iff a=0$ (you don't need $a\geq 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you do a little bit complicate. $$|a|=0\iff (a=0\quad \text{or}\quad  -a=0)\iff a=0.$$

Moreover, you don't need that fact that $a\geq 0$.

Comment: It is strange that you would have BOTH "a= 0" and "a>= 0".  a= 0 is certainly included in a>= 0 but just a= 0 is more precise.

Comment: @user247327: I don't have both ! I actually already made the remark to the OP that he doesn't need $a\geq 0$. Could you give more precision on your comment ?

Comment: I am sorry maybe I was not clear, $|a| = 0$ iff $a = 0$ is a proposition and $|a| \ge 0$ is other proposition

Comment: which side? (I don't understand you)

Comment: Dear @JoseVega: if $a\geq 0$, then $|a|=a\geq 0$. If $a\leq 0$, then $|a|=-a\geq 0$. finish :-)

Comment: @Surb if $a \le 0$, then $|a| = -a \ge 0$ I disagree because the target is $a=0$

Comment: So may be you can write an unconfused assertion ! What I read is $$\ \ $$ 1) prove that $a=0\iff |a|=0$. $$\ \ \ $$2) Prove that $|a|\geq 0$. $$\ \ $$ Anyways, it's not important now, I quite ! Ask somebody else. Good evening.